# ORACLE DB ¿INSERT - DELETE -UPDATE dentro de un vista sin modificar la tabla origial?

Tags: oracle, plsql

tengo una tabla empleados que tiene los campos, ID, NOMBRE, DIRECCIÓN, SALARIO.
Lo que quiero hacer es modificar los salarios de las personas que cobren menos de 40.000, y hacer un `UPDATE` del campo SALARIO para esas personas en particular. Para no hacerlo sobre la tabla empleados me cree una vista de la tabla, la vista tiene la siguiente sintaxis:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  VIEW_EMPLEADO AS SELECT * FROM EMPLEADO;
```

Ahora mi problema es que cuando hago `UPDATE` sobre `VIEW_EMPLEADO` y modifico el salario, también se me modifica la tabla original `EMPLEADO`.

Como puedo resolver este problema?
MIL GRACIAS!!

Comment: una vista es justamente eso, una vista de la tabla.. no es una tabla nueva.. cual seria tu punto al tratar de hacer eso?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es, modificar los campos sin tocar los datos originales, en caso de que haga alguna macana, no se si se entiende.

Comment: si se entiende, pero para eso tenes que tener un entorno de prueba, otro de pre produccion y otro de produccion.. Las vistas, son solamente eso, vistas de la tabla.. son la tabla vista de una forma en particular..

Comment: Ok.. perfecto muchas gracias! @gbianchi !

Comment: tambien podes sacar el autocommit de tu ide, de esa forma los cambios no van a la base de datos hasta que no haces commit.. por si queres hacer un rollback...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle no permite UPDATE sobre columnas calculadas. Si el nuevo salario (el SET del UPDATE) lo puedes transformar en un CASE, por ejemplo, aumentar el 10%, usalo en tu vista.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN salario < 40000 THEN salario*1.1
         WHEN salario >= 40000 THEN salario
       END salario
```

Otra opción es usar un trigger `INSTEAD OF` nulo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_v_emp
  INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON view_empleados
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  null;
END;
/
```